# Secondary D-Link DIR 600 Connects via Ethernet, but not via Wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm running an old D-Link DIR 600 v. B2 as a secondary router for a VPN connection.  I'm in the Philippines and my primary router is a cellular router called a SmartBro LTE Home.  It has a single ethernet port that I've connected to the internet port on the D-Link DIR 600.

- I'm using Windows 10 on an HP Pavillion g4 laptop
- The primary router (SmartBro device) is IP 192.168.1.1
- Secondary router (D-Link) is IP 192.168.2.1
- Both have a mask of 255.255.255.0
- The routers are placed about 4.5 feet away from each other (it was the longest ethernet cable I had readily available)
- The secondary router has been successfully flashed (a couple of times due to hard resetting the router after a forgotten admin password) with the latest version of DD-WRT
- I haven't installed a VPN yet on the secondary router.  I'm waiting until I can get the wireless signal (first things first!)

  1. The laptop gets good internet signal when connected to the ethernet or wireless of the primary router
  2. The laptop gets good internet when connected to an ethernet port on the secondary router
  3. There is no internet when connected to the wireless of the secondary router.
  4. Even when connected to the secondary router (WITH GOOD INTERNET), the internet indicator on the secondary (D-Link DIR 600) is solid orange.

I need to be able to connect wirelessly to the secondary router, but can't get it to work.  Any ideas?  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
James